# Nodejs API init behavior when using multiple module requires

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sentry

I'm using Sentry in several node modules. I initialize it in `admin.js`:

```js
// admin.js
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');

Sentry.init({
  dsn: functions.config().sentry.dsn,
  environment: functions.config().env.mode,
});

module.exports = { Sentry };
```

I understand that node is 'require once' (caches after the first time) and returns the same object after that, so that multiple requires behave as a single require.

My question relates to the order these `require` statements are run, and whether I should use option #1 or #2 below in other modules (or if it matters at all):

```js
// utils.js
// option #1
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');

testFn () {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch (err) {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
  }
}
```

```js
// utils.js
// option #2
const { Sentry } = require('./admin');

testFn () {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch (err) {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
  }
}
```

If I use option #1, is it a possibility that Sentry won't be properly initialized in `utils.js` when `captureException` is called?

If both options work, is one preferred over the other in terms of a best practice?

Comment: Only option 2 is correct. `admin` is not imported in option 1.

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, you're saying that although sentry gets initialized in admin.js, if using option 1, sentry will not work in utils.js?

Comment: It won't if admin wasn't imported before utils in a module that imports utils, and it will if admin was. This sort of uncertainty indicates a problem. If utils depends on the code from admin and needs it to work correctly, it should import it explicitly.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. That makes perfect sense. Many thanks!